# Showing a hidden button based on the fill-up event of an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a datetime field and a hidden button. I want to show the button only when the datetime field is filled up. Here is my code -

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' id='datetimepicker'>

<button type="button" id="just-a-button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">
  Button
</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i'
});

$("#datetimepicker").focusout(function() {
  if ($("#datetimepicker").val()) {
    $('button#just-a-button').show();
  }
});
```

Live demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ni8mr/j6Lc004r/).

Button becomes visible when outside area of the input field is clicked after **datetime** selection.

I want to make the button visible instantly after **datetime** selection. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listen to [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event and reuse jQuery objects like this:

```
$("#datetimepicker").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $('button#just-a-button').show();
  }
});
```

---

EDIT: **alternative solution** (and possibly better) - you can use callback function provided by the plugin as written [here](http://www.xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#onChangeDateTime):

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i',
  onChangeDateTime: function() {
    $('button#just-a-button').show();
  }
});
```

..this way you can remove the code from first solution, also you can play around with this callback function to target multiple datetimepicker objects with single code

Comment: Thanks, it has helped.

Comment: Alternative solution is more standard.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onchange`

```
$("#datetimepicker").on('change',function() {
if ($("#datetimepicker").val()) {
$('button#just-a-button').show();
}});
```